# Eclipse ADT bundle hangs when phone is connected

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Eclipse with the ADT runs fine for me on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. However, whenever I plug in my phone with Eclipse open, it tends to hang and max out my CPU for an indefinite amount of time. Even when it doesn't hang immediately after plugging in my phone, it will intermittently seize up and not respond to any input for anywhere from a minute to 10+ minutes if the phone is at all connected. When run on the command line, this is the only output:

```
(ADT:11808): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:11808): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
```

etc...

After researching these errors, I believe this is not the root cause as Eclipse does this even when my phone isn't connected and it runs fine.

The logs are similarly useless and only mention that the workspace wasn't saved after I am forced to shut down Eclipse.

For reference, the phone I am connecting is a Droid 2 Global running Android 2.3.4.

Comment: Did you try a fresh install of Eclipse (for example the one in the [ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) ) to see if it comes from Eclipse or from your phone ?

Comment: Try to connect your phone without eclipse open. Does your pc hang? (if you connect with adb ..)

Answer (score 1):

Bugs when dealing with ADT + Eclipse are common.

> ***Update to the latest ADT and this must be fixed***

I'm using my phone as well, to debug with the latest ADT and am facing no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are running 64bit Ubuntu... I had similar issue under 64bit Debian 7 (Wheezy) and solved it by running 32bit Eclipse Juno under 32bit Java 1.7.

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem - you need to clear the logcat buffer (bug in adt).

before plugging inn the phone, open a terminal and run "adb logcat", it's not a 100% fix, but it reduces the amount of crashes. Also, reducing the amount of log data your app produces will help a lot (as once again, too much log crashes the plugin).

Funnily enough, this was fixed just before Christmas, but regressed on the following update.

Anyway, I'm submitting a bug report as I type this.